# Create a BaseViewModel on a common library

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a  common library that need to be shared among my main WPF app and its plugins...
In the common library I have a BaseViewModel with this code

```
    public Dispatcher RootDispatcher
    {
        get
        {
            _rootDispatcher = _rootDispatcher ??
                (App.Current != null
                    ? App.Current.Dispatcher
                    : Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
            return _rootDispatcher;
        }
        // unit tests can get access to this via InternalsVisibleTo
        internal set
        {
            _rootDispatcher = value;
        }
    }

    protected void TriggerSafeEvent(EventHandler eve, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (RootDispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            if (eve != null)
                eve.Invoke(this, args);
        }
        else
        {
            RootDispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                if (eve != null)
                    eve.Invoke(this, args);
            });
        }
    }
```

So the consumer ViewModel could call an event in a way like this without to be worried wherever thread belongs from the main thread:

```
    MyViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    ..
            TriggerSafeEvent(MyEventHandler, MyEventArgs);

    }
```

Since the common library is not a WPF application, the App object is not resolved.

I think that this approach could be wrong, however I feel that is not an uncommon practice to share often call methods within a base view model.

What is the best solution to handle with *App* object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dependency injection. This is off the top of my head but it'll work.

```
public interface IDispatcherProvider {
    Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }
}
```

BaseViewModel

```
public static IDispatcherProvider DispatcherProvider { get; set; }
```

Interface implementation:

```
public class DispatcherProviderImplementation : IDispatcherProvider
{
    public DispatcherProviderImplementation(Func<Dispatcher> getDispatcher)
    {
        _getDispatcher = getDispatcher;
    }

    private Func<Dispatcher> _getDispatcher;

    public virtual Dispatcher Dispatcher => _getDispatcher?.Invoke();

    //  If your compiler won't accept the above, try this
    /*
    public virtual Dispatcher Dispatcher {
        get {
            return (_getDispatcher == null) ? null : _getDispatcher();
        }
    }
    */
}
```

App

```
    static App()
    {
        BaseViewModel.DispatcherProvider 
            = new DispatcherProviderImplementation(() => (App.Current != null
                ? App.Current.Dispatcher
                : Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, public virtual Dispatcher Dispatcher => _getDispatcher.?.Invoke(); doesn't work, is there any error ?

Comment: @fstarred Sorry, typo -- it's fixed now in the answer. Should be `_getDispatcher?.Invoke();` What version of C# are you using?

Comment: @fstarred If your compiler still doesn't like that, I've provided a version of that property that's compatible with C#5

Comment: Looks like it works!!! Thank you so much, do you know if I could use any DI framework to accomplish this ?

Comment: @fstarred No idea, I don't do much DI I'm afraid.

Comment: @fstarred You can use StructureMap with something like "public static void AddConatinerRegistry(object obj, Type registryType)
        {
            Container.Configure(c =>
            {
                c.For(registryType).Use(obj);
            });
        }",

Comment: @dman I don't know if fstarred will get a notification for that, should you @ him?